# Wiring one switch controlling 3 light fixtures

Tags: wiring

In the first fixture I have a hot wire coming in with its white neutral. I also have coming in a cable with a black(not hot),white,and red wire. The third cable, black-not hot and white leads to the second light, etc. The switch is not powered at a all. The only power is the hot black coming into the fixture. I wire it successfully so the 3 lights light up, BUT THE SWITCH DOES NOT TURN THEM ON OR OFF. It seems I am not getting power to the switch. This was all working fine before I wanted to change the 3 fixtures, and the switch worked perfectly for all three. But I forgot to take a photo of the wiring or sketch a diagram how it was wired. So I am stuck now. Thanks for your help.
-Richard

Comment: What wires are going into the switch box??

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the wiring as it stands now, including the wiring at the switch box?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the black/white/red goes to your switch, it should be:

- Black = Hot
- White = Neutral (only needed for a smart/motion/timer/etc. but required by code for new installations)
- Red = Switched Hot

So at the first fixture:

- Incoming Hot Black -> Black to switch
- Incoming Neutral White -> White to switch *and* white to next fixture *and* neutral of fixture
- Red from switch -> Hot of fixture *and* black to next fixture hot.